# How to download files from server and rename it synchronously in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, server, download, synchronous

I want to every client can download files from the server's folder, and I don't want that all those files be saved in the /download folder.

I thought first download the file and then rename it, but I need to run this code synchronously.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){

        const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/apple.jpg`;
        const destination = `C:/Users/steve/Downloads/apple.jpg`;

        res.download(file);

         fs.renameSync(destination,"C:/Users/steve/Desktop/downloadedimg.jpg");     
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're conflating the client side vs. the server side.  The code you provided is for node.js on the server side.  You're not able to specify where on the client's computer a file is downloaded.  You can provide a different name for the file that's being downloaded:

```
res.download(`${__dirname}/upload-folder/apple.jpg`, 'orange.jpg');
```

Reference: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: I got it, but there is a way to set where to download those files? Specifically, I need to download files and get organize them in a folder in categories. Where the user can choose the path where put that folder. Thanks for the answer